# Scroll Horizontal Slideshow

Tags: javascript

Basically, after about 4 seconds, I want a set of 3 thumbnails to rotate (as a group) to another set of 3 thumbnails. Here's an example, but imagine 3 separate images instead of 1. http://pk3solutions.com/2013_Fall/cas222%20%28Intermediate%20Website%20Creation%29/nifty/Index.html I also want those images to have click-able links.

Here's what I have so far: http://pk3solutions.com/2013_Fall/cas222%20%28Intermediate%20Website%20Creation%29/final_project/portfolio.html

ALSO, I want to be able to use those links immediately under those thumbnails, to switch the set to a different 3. Is there a way to do this without making separate web pages? Basically those links are a "filter" so to speak.

This is all I have so far:

```
$('#s1').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    prev:   '#prev1', 
    next:   '#next1', 
    timeout: 0, 
    rev: true 
});
```

Comment: What was the question again?

Answer (score 0):

jquery cycle

```
 jQuery("#slideshow").cycle({
    timeout:0, // no autoplay
    fx: 'fade', //
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev'
 });
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8WTer/)!

Comment: you mean rotate image also image horintally scroll?

Comment: yes just like that, thank you @user3069157 but instead of one image, a set of 3 images rotating.